# Type error: strzal[nr.length] is undefined

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
var strzal = [];
var nr = Object.keys(strzal);
strzal[nr.length][0] = new Image();
strzal[nr.length][0].src = 'data/strzal_01.png';
ctx.drawImage(strzal[nr.length][0], gracz.x, gracz.y);
strzal[nr][1] = gracz.x;
strzal[nr][2] = gracz.y;
strzal[nr][3] = setInterval(functionName, 150);
strzal[nr][4] = gracz.zasieg;
```

I have error in "strzal[nr.length][0] = new Image();". Something in this line is wrong, but I don't know what. When I added [0] an error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strzal` is empty, and you're trying to acces a variable on an index. You should change it to

```
strzal[nr.length] = array(new Image());
```

***More info:***

This can be done:

```
variable[new_index] = other_variable;
```

This can't be done, because it doesn't exist yet:

```
variable[new_index][second_new_index] = other_variable;
```

Javascript doesn't create the indexes all the way, so keep that in mind!

Comment: @Mahok No problem! If it wouldn't be too much to ask, could you mark this answer as accepted and / or upvote it? It will help others find this solution to!